# Testing config module with mocha that depends on environment variable process.env.APP_ENV

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, environment-variables, mocha.js

I'm working on a project that uses the value in `process.env.APP_ENV` in order to select the appropiate config file for the current environment:

```
import prodParams from './production';
import stgParams from './staging';
import devParams from './development';

let params = devParams;
switch (process.env.APP_ENV) {
  case 'production':
    params = prodParams;
    break;
  case 'staging':
    params = stgParams;
    break;
  default:
    params = devParams;
}

export default params;
```

I'm trying to test this with the following code (not yet with assertions):

```
import params from '../../../parameters';
...

it.only('should return the appropriate config ', (done) => {
    process.env.APP_ENV = 'production';
    console.log(params);
    done();
});
```

However when I set environment variable `process.env.APP_ENV` as shown above it still reaches the module as undefined, so it always returns the development config instead of the production environment.

Setting aside the test part, the functionality is working fine, but I would like to test it regardless.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I would recommend to avoid to rely on global properties such `process.env` in all your modules. Read the environment variables in the entry point of your app/test setup and pass them around. In your `parameters.js` export a `function` rather than an object that takes as argument the environment to load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` statements are executed before any other code, so you can't make this work using `import`.

You can *somewhat* get it working with `require`, if you require the parameters file *after* you have set the environment variable:

```
process.env.APP_ENV = 'production';
let params = require('../../../parameters').default;
...
```

However, this still isn't great, because it'll work just once because of the cache that `require` maintains (a subsequent test which sets `APP_ENV` to a different value won't work).

A workaround would be to have `parameters.js` export a function that you'd call:

```
// parameters.js
export default function() {
  let params = devParams;
  switch (process.env.APP_ENV) {
    ...
  }
  return params;
}

// test.js
import getParams from '../../../parameters';
...

process.env.APP_ENV = 'production';
let params = getParams();
```

Or set `APP_ENV` externally:

```
$ env APP_ENV='production' mocha ...
```

Comment: I have got the same issue, and I am 'require'-ing the testee script after modifying the process.env. Yet, I get the value which I set through my .bash_profile. Why is that?